# Gulp + Shopify Theme Kit for Sass with color functions

Tags: sass, gulp, shopify, gulp-sass, shopify-template

I have a pretty annoying problem. I'm using the last version of Shopify's Theme Kit, which doesn't allow to place subfolders inside the assets folder. So, for this reason, I had to place my SASS files into another folder with all it' structure, set a Gulp task to translate it to a single file in the assets folder.

But I still wanna use the theme variables that can be set by the user from within the Shopify Theme Editor. And I cannot get my head around this issue!

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./styles/theme.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(rename('theme.scss.liquid'))
        .pipe(replace('"{{', '{{'))
        .pipe(replace('}}"', '}}'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {

    return gulp.watch(['./styles/**/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
});
```

And I get an error:

```
Message:
    styles/partials/_general.scss
Error: argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color
        on line 71 of styles/partials/_general.scss, in function `lighten`
        from line 71 of styles/partials/_general.scss
        from line 12 of styles/theme.scss
>>          color: lighten($textColor, 20%);

   ----------^
```

Someone has some idea on how to solve this? It seems like I cannot use the SASS color functions anymore! Cause if then I remove the given line in the error message, everything goes ok!

Comment: Did you define the variables on top?